# Is iOS in-app consumable purchase actually required to be restored?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

The section on Restoring Previous Completed Purchases from this [document](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf) it says:

"As described above, the different In-App Purchase types have different requirements for whether previous purchases must be restored to users devices."

Then in the table it says:

- **In-App Purchase Type:** Consumable
- **Restore Required?** No
- **Transaction Restoration Mechanism:** Your server may track purchases and allow user to restore

The wording is unclear. It seems to mean...you don't have to restore consumables if you don't want to. But if you do, then you need your own server. It's your (the developer's) choice.

Do Consumable In-App Purchases HAVE to be restored if the user deletes the app and later reinstalls it? Or will Apple allow apps that won't?

Thanks

Comment: You answered your own question. It's not required but you can if you want to.

Comment: "Restore Required? No" What exactly is unclear?

Comment: @rmaddy, Kevin, Thx for reply. But I just want to make sure my app won't get rejected. Here is an example: User buys 100 consumable coins. User uses 20 coins. User has 80 coins left. User uninstalls the app. User later redownloads the app on the same device. Do I have to restore 80 coins?

Comment: Not as far as Apple is concerned. But if you do not, your users will be furious.

Answer (score 1):

You said it yourself:

> Restore Required? No

The reason is: it's a consumable. If I buy an extra life in Candy Crush, I have presumably used it. There is nothing to restore later if I install Candy Crush on a different device.

(Not that I have ever played Candy Crush. No.)

Comment: First of all, the following damaging photos reveal clearly that matt does play Candy Crush! lol thx for the reply. I'm more concerned about reinstalling on the same device. See my example to rmaddy, kevin above. What about that case?